# Implement socketcluster in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to use socketcluster in my android application. I used https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client-android but I am facing a problem in connecting to server.

This connects to server through javaScript. It uses **webViewJavaScriptBridge**.
When the webview loads the url,  it displays the following error in logcat.

```
09-07 18:00:22.972: D/WebViewJavascriptBridge---(25415): 
  Uncaught ReferenceError: WebViewJavascriptBridge3 is not defined line:1
```

If there is any better solution, please suggest.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can find latest **native java/android-socketcluster-client** here, https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java. If you want to know how to build **'android chat application'** using socketcluster, visit [Building a chat application using socketcluster](https://medium.com/@sachinshinde7676/building-a-chat-app-for-android-using-socketcluster-in-node-js-90a4ae6c3577#.y70dqf28j)

Answer (score 1):

This client is not being developed anymore. Members of the SC community are currently trying to build a native Android client. See https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/issues/208 - Feel free to get involved.